# Why doesn't my background stretch behind my contentbox?

Tags: html, css

I cannot get the background to stretch behind the contentbox. The strange thing is, it works with Internet Explorer, but not with Firefox.

I hope it is enough to give you a link, since I do not know where the problem is in the code, it would not make much sense to post the whole code in here.

> http://www.yiip.de/arbeit/testlayout/standard_template.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding the following 'clearfix' style to your wrappers

```
.clearfix:after {
    content:"\0020";
    display:block;
    height:0;
    clear:both;
    visibility:hidden;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.clearfix {display:block;}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also add `overflow:hidden;` to `#shadow`.  That will clear the floats without having to put additional markup in your html.

Comment: This would be the solution I found also, Vote up for Emily

Answer (score -1):

You need to clear your 3 floated divs for the containing div to expand vertically around them. The easiest way to do this is to add

```
<br clear='both' />
```

after the third floated div (but within the container div).